# VB WebBrowser control auto click button on website

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I need use webBrowser Control to auto click one button on website. I know how to write code if I can get ( Name or Id ), but this website not set button name or ID.

Here is code button on website:

```
  <input type="submit" alt="Login" value="Login"/>
```

How am I supposed to use vb webBrowser control in this case?

Comment: Look for the form tag the button belongs to.

Comment: @Derek Curtis , i trying with your code and your link ....but it still not working.....i give you my website.....can you help me to complete it ? i will use one button to login auto on webBrowser Control on this website [link](http://ssr138.com/login_ssr.cfm) Hope that you can help ...Please

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the web browser control to do any such thing (I also assume you mean you're using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser in a WinForms app or the WPF equivalent in a WPF application)

If you need to 'click' a button on a web page.. what you really mean is that you need to submit an HTTP request to the website.

So, let's say your target website has something like this... and you want to click the 'submit' button.. but like you said, it has no id.

```
<form action="http://example.com/foo/bar/login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <input type="submit" alt="Login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Here is an example of how to accomplish this in C#: [post data through httpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550965/post-data-through-httpwebrequest)

To accomplish the same thing in VB.NET you'd use:

```
Dim request As New WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/foo/bar/login")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Using (Dim writer As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    writer.Write("username=whatever")
    writer.Write("password=p@$$w0rD")
End Using
Dim response = request.GetResponse()
```

Comment: thanks you so much but i am not clear about your code because never write with C# , can you help me to write in VB ?
thanks

Comment: Sure, basically when you're viewing a browser in a web page, it's an easy way for human beings to pull and push data to a web server.  If you're doing it through code, you need to forget the web browser altogether.  You can talk with a web browser in VB using the WebRequest/WebResponse objects (or the HttpWebRequest).  Here's a really good write up on the whole process - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6554/How-to-use-HttpWebRequest-and-HttpWebResponse-in-N.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, that link is in C# as well.  Here's a short VB example: http://www.808.dk/?code-vbnet-httpwebrequest

Comment: i will try to watch this link....but sorry i have feeling that your below code working but i don't know about how to use it in VB form ....however i will check your link to understand but if you have any free time , Please help me convert this code to VB
Thanks

Comment: i trying with your code and your link ....but it still not working.....i give you my website.....can you help me to complete it ? i will use one button to login auto on webBrowser Control on this website [link](http://ssr138.com/login_ssr.cfm) Hope that you can help ...Please