# Invalid URI when calling HTTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

I've written a console app that calls a RESTful web service sending XML requests over HTTP which returns XML responses.  Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create("<?xml version=1.0 encoding=ISO-8859-1?>
<Request xmlns=https://sapiqa.overstock.com/api><MerchantKey>"+MerchantKey+"
</MerchantKey><AthenticationKey>"+AuthenticationKey+"</AuthenticationKey><"+APIMethod+"
/></Request>");
wrq.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array. Strip out unnecessary text. 
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(URL.Replace(APIMethod, ""));
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest. 
wrq.ContentType = "text/xml";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest. 
wrq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = wrq.GetRequestStream();
// Write the data to the request stream. 
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object. 
dataStream.Close();
// Get the response. 
WebResponse response = wrq.GetResponse();
// Display the status. 
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server. 
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access. 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content. 
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Display the content. 
GetOrders2Response = responseFromServer;
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

// Clean up the streams. 
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
Console.ReadKey();
```

When I run this code, I receive the error stating:

```
Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
```

How do I remedy by WebRequest to send properly formatted XML and receive a response in XML as well?

Comment: Making POST request requires a little more work. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2550965/56778. Or do a search for [httpwebrequest post].

Comment: @JimMischel Could you elaborate a bit further in an answer?

Comment: The example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx is very detailed. There are literally *hundreds* of examples out there. A simple Google search on `httpwebrequest post example` will give you lots of samples to choose from.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for this link.  I'm still not clear as to how to send my MerchantKey and AuthenticationKey values as part of the POST request?

Comment: I don't know how to use that REST API, either. We've shown you how to make a POST request. It's up to you to figure out how to format the payload (your data) so that the server will accept it. Maybe you could find some documentation for that API call.

Comment: @SidC - Jim is right.  You can look at the `.Headers` property, but it may or may not be what you need.  But that is a documentation / example issue, not a URI / POST issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error and documentation *clearly* state, `WebRequest.Create` takes a URL, not a POST payload.

You need to pass the URL to `Create()`, and write the XML payload to the request stream.

Comment: So, how do I go about constructing the XML payload you've mentioned?  If the Crete method take a simple URL, how do I pass in my MerchantKey and AuthenticationKey variable values?

Comment: @SidC - Look at the answer that Jim Mischel linked to above.