# Post data to web API

Tags: wpf, api

I've been trying to send data to a web API VIA post. But it doesn't seem to be sending it.

Here's how I do it.

```
 var baseAddress = "http://192.168.0.103/vchatapi/api/Images?gsmNumber=" + profileNumberLbl.Content + "&content=" + base64 + "&contentType=image/" + contentType;
 var http = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(baseAddress));
  http.Accept = "application/json";
  http.ContentType = "application/json";
  http.Method = "POST";
```

This code works with get:

```
var baseAddress = "http://192.168.0.103/vchatapi/api/SendSMSVerificationCode?gsmNumber=" + areCode + mobile + "&udid=123456";
var http = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(baseAddress));
http.Accept = "application/json";
http.ContentType = "application/json";
http.Method = "GET";

try
                    {
                        var response = http.GetResponse();

                        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                        var content = sr.ReadToEnd();

                        verificationCode = verificationCode.FromJson(content);
                        if (!verificationCode.Equals(""))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(this, "Verification Code: " + verificationCode);
                            verificationTextBox.IsEnabled = true;
                            areaCodeCB.IsEnabled = false;
                            mobileNumberTB.IsEnabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Number");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message);
                    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a POST, you would be sending the content in the body of the request. You would need to get hold of the request's stream and write data to it. The following answer post has a very concise example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551006/1184056